# jQuery clear specific value of multiple input file on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload

I have upload file form with multiple choose.

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    Browse <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" onchange="preview_image();" multiple/>
</span>

<div class="image_preview"></div>
```

Then after choose the file, it will show the image thumbnail preview with delete action for each image.

```
function preview_image() 
{
    var total_file = document.getElementById("image").files.length;

    if($("#totalImageList").val() == "")
    {
        var totalImageList = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        var totalImageList = $("#totalImageList").val();
    }

    var total = parseInt(total_file)+parseInt(totalImageList);

    $(".uploadError").hide();

    if((total) < 6)
    {
        $("#totalImageList").val(total);

        for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++)
        {
            $('.image_preview').append("<div class='imageList'><img src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'/><div class='removeImage'>Remove</div></div>");

            $(".removeImage").click(function()
            {
                $(this).parent(".imageList").remove();

                $("#totalImageList").val($(".imageList").length);
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $(".uploadError").show();
    }
}
```

Please see below image:
[image]

And now I want when I click image specific Remove, it will only clear the value for that image specific Remove click.

How to do that?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle, it ll be easier to help you :)

Comment: as far as I know, you can't edit the value stored in the file input.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the click image only you can do it in following way.

```js
$('.removeImage').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Is it including remove the click image value?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave are you talking about src attribute of `img` tag?

Comment: Yes Sir... So when one of image remove, it will update the current image value without that remove image value

Comment: Yes it will remove

Comment: Just now tried, it's not clear the value. I tried to submit and upload, assume I have 5 files to be upload, then I try to remove 2 files. When I try to submit, it still upload 5 files